# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0, please help resolve

Tags: java, arrays, loops, hashset

I was creating a social network using java data structures and had used hashsets to display likes and friends and suggest uncommon friends using a template from roseindia.net

I managed to get the code working last night but now when I run it, it presents the error from the title. Does anyone know how to resolve this? The previous threads were not very helpful. This is my code:

```
package SocialNetwork;
```

Comment: My God, the lack of generics is kind of extreme on a Java 1.7 environment. Using ArrayList<String> would clearly help.

Comment: Same for HashSet<String> and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing `arr` with size as `0`

```
            int maxSize = 0;
            ArrayInObs arr;
            arr = new
            ArrayInObs(maxSize);
```

You need to pass some higher value to it (say 20).

Same for `aar2` as well:

```
            int maxSize2 = 0;
            ArrayInObs arr2;
            arr2 = new
            ArrayInObs(maxSize2);
```

Comment: Thank you, it is running now but still says that arr 2 is assigned but never used. Does this affect the running of the program?

Comment: Since arr2 is not used, so it is not going to create any problem. It is just a warning. Are you using some IDE (like eclipse)? If yes then you can see it as warning in the editor itself.

Comment: yes I am using Intellij. It is giving a separate error for the Hash set, "unchecked call to 'add(E)' as a member of raw type java.util.ArrayList. I have never seen this but my tutor said not to worry about it. Should I?

Comment: No need to worry but you should fix your code to remove every warning.

Comment: Do you know how I would remove this particular warning? I have never encountered it before and the explanations online are very vague.

Comment: Change `ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList();` to `List<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>();` in your code. `Set s = new HashSet();` to `Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();`

Comment: Do this everywhere in the code. In short try to use generic while using collection `<>`. If you are happy with my suggestions then accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

You need to initialize "maxSize".

Please replace `int maxSize` with appropriate value in main method, like `int maxSize = 100`;

It should work after making above change.